# ESXi shutdown by UPS system

Tags: vmware-esxi, ups

If I use a script to shutdown my ESXi server in the event of a power outage, do I need to shutdown each VM or will ESXi shutdown all of the VMs for me? When I mean shutdown I mean a graceful shutdown not a hard power off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESXi will do this for you IF you have configured it to do so. Check the configuration tab and the virtual machine startup/shutdown setting. Ensure it is enabled and that you have defined your individual VM startup/shutdown requirements.

Comment: I'm still amazed ESXi (and ESX) requires tricky VMa scripting to enable UPS-controlled shutdown. VMware should really get this built in.

Comment: Well I am aware of product in the APC powerchute line. It is for ESX I don't if it for ESXi. But I am not made of that kind of money so I and taking the homebrew approach.

Comment: Tell me about it. The lack of a simple UPS management page in ESXi is laughable in this day and age.